# How to disable functionality that takes place after a click event using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button on my page which, when clicked, listens for another button being clicked and then performs an AJAX call. For example:

```
$( 'button#a' ).click( function() {

    $( 'button#b' ).click( function() {
        // Perform an AJAX call here.
    });

});
```

Here is a demo of my code so far:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cbtbsbhd/)

I want to disable the ajax call functionality **if** a third button `button#c` is clicked at any time during the time that the page is loaded. I'm at a loss at how this can be done. Hoping someone can suggest an approach.

Comment: In the demo, click on button a and then button c and then button b. The AJAX call fires. I don't want that because button c was clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should not code click event inside click, but after modifying in your code.

```
var third_click= false; 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( 'button#c' ).click( function() {
        third_click = true;
    })

    $( 'button#a' ).click( function() {

        $( 'button#b' ).click( function() {
            if( !third_click ) {
                // Perform an AJAX call here.
                alert( 'ajax call in progress' );
            } else {
                alert( 'Can\'t call ajax' );
            }
        });

    });
})
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/qeojLmn4/1/) is demo.

Comment: "Should not code click event inside click" - why is that?

Comment: @henrywright I think it's just not considered "nice coding"... But if you wanted to avoid that, you could just do more or less the same thing with `button#a` as it's done with `button#c` in the code above: http://jsfiddle.net/Niffler/qeojLmn4/2/

Answer (score 0):

What if you used button a to hide button b until a is clicked and then show button b and so fourth until your results are displayed as you with.

example:

```
  $('.btnB').hide();

 $('.btnA').on('click', function() {
  $('.btnB').toggle();
});
```

Unless it needs to all display at one time this method wouldn't be able to work in that type of situation

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the click events from #a and b# when clicking on #c with:

```
$('#c').click(function () {
    $('#a,#b').off('click')
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/cbtbsbhd/1/)**